# Conform an image URL String to Viewable protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Im trying to implement [Viewer](https://github.com/3lvis/Viewer) pod package in my `Swift` project and according to the documentation I need to create a collection of items that conform to the `Viewable` protocol below.

How do I conform an image `String` in my `for-loop` below to the `Viewable` protocol below?

Protocol:

```
public enum ViewableType: String {
    case image
    case video
}

public protocol Viewable {
    var type: ViewableType { get }
    var assetID: String? { get }
    var url: String? { get }
    var placeholder: UIImage { get }

    func media(_ completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)
}
```

This is my code:

```
    var images = [String]()
    var viewableImages = [Viewable]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

     loadViewableImages()

    }

    fileprivate func loadViewableImages(){

            viewableImages.removeAll()

            for image in images{
                viewableImages.append(image) //need to append a Viewable type image not a String
            }


}//end func
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better option is to create a separate class (`Image` in this case) that will confirm to `Viewable` protocol:

```swift
class Image: Viewable {
    var type: ViewableType {
        return .image
    }
    let assetID: String? = UUID().uuidString
    let placeholder = UIImage()

    let url: String?

    init(url: String) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func media(_ completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
         guard let url = url else { 
            completion(nil, nil)
            return
         }
         guard let imageURL = URL(string: url) else {
            completion(nil, nil)
            return
         }
         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { (data, response, error) in
             DispatchQueue.main.async { //all changes to UI must be called on main thread
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                    completion(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                completion(UIImage(data: data), nil)
            }
      }.resume()
    }
}
```

and you will need to change loop to:

```swift
for image in images{
    viewableImages.append(Image(url: image))
}
```